# .NET Equivalent of SQL Server STDistance

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlgeography, geographic-distance

I can use the following SQL to calculate the distance between a fixed location and the location against the venues in the database.

```
SELECT Location.STDistance(geography::Point(51, -2, 4326)) * 0.00062137119 FROM Venues
```

Please note the distance returned is in miles and the Location field is a geography type.

I was wondering what is the equivalent of this in .NET which would return the same values. This method would have the following signature:

```
public static double Distance(location1Latitude, location1Longitude, location2Latitude, location2Longitude) {
    return ...;
}
```

I know I could call the database method in .NET but I don't wish to do this. I'm hoping there is a formula to calculate the distance. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate distance of two geo points in km c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544286/calculate-distance-of-two-geo-points-in-km-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to compute the [Geographical distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance) to compute the distance manually.  There are [many different techniques and formulas to do this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance#Flat-surface_formulae), each with different underlying assumptions (ie: a spherical earth, ellipsoidal earth, etc).

A common option is the haversine formula, with a [C# implementation available here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6545031/65358).

Answer (score 7):

I believe you can simply add `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` as a reference and then use the [`SqlGeometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry.aspx) type like any other .NET type, including calling the [`STDistance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry.stdistance.aspx) method.

Comment: Also available as a Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Answer (score 1):

this is [very well explained here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Jun/21/Basic-Spatial-Data-with-SQL-Server-and-Entity-Framework-50). 
Shortly: with EF5 (to be more specific, with .net 4.5) Microsoft included the type [DbGeography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Let say you already have a bunch of lat/long, you can then create a DbGeography object easily using an helper like:

```
public static DbGeography CreatePoint(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    var text = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat,
                             "POINT({0} {1})", longitude, latitude);
    // 4326 is most common coordinate system used by GPS/Maps
    return DbGeography.PointFromText(text, 4326);
}
```

Once you got a two or more points (DbGeography) you got everything to calculate the [Distance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.distance.aspx) between them:

```
var distance = point1.Distance(point2)
```

Comment: Not available in .NET Core, for reference.