# How to use System.Spatial.GeographyPoint

Tags: c#, geography

I need a function to calculate distance between point A and point B.

Namespace `System.Spatial` seems to be exactly what I need, but I can't figure how to use it.

`IPoint` is an interface that provides `Latitude` and `Longitude`, both of type `double`.

First try :

```
  public static double CalculateDistance(IPoint pointA, IPoint pointB)
  {
     var gp1 = GeographyPoint.Create(pointA.Latitude, pointA.Longitude);
     var gp2 = GeographyPoint.Create(pointB.Latitude, pointB.Longitude);

     return gp1.Distance(gp2) ?? 0;
  }
```

That ends with a `NotImplementedException`on `point1.Distance(point2)`. The message is in french, but basically it says "No operation registered. Please provide operation using property SpatialImplementation.CurrentImplementation.Operations".

Ok, I will try this then :

```
public static double CalculateDistance(IPoint pointA, IPoint pointB)
{
   var gp1 = GeographyPoint.Create(pointA.Latitude, pointA.Longitude);
   var gp2 = GeographyPoint.Create(pointB.Latitude, pointB.Longitude);

   return SpatialImplementation.CurrentImplementation.Operations.Distance(gp1, gp2);
}
```

Now I got a `NullReferenceException` on `SpatialImplementation.CurrentImplementation.Operations`.

Msdn is not much verbose about this.

Anyone can explain how to get these implementations ?

Comment: How are you calling that method, and have you implemented `IPoint` interface with a class ?

Comment: Sure I have implemented it. It just provides latitude and longitude. The errors are exactly what I said. I'm calling this from unit test for now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IMHO you shouldn't use `System.Spatial`. It's an half-baked library created for OData interoperability with Spatial, namely for WCF Data-Services.

You can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn259729%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) for more information. Also, most of the classes on that library are abstract, hence up-to-you to be implement most-of-it.

Also, and even worse, they're incompatible with Entity Framework spatial support.

I'm not sure what kind of project you're on but I would suggest these guidelines:

- if you just need to calculate distances between points just copy an implementation of the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) or [Vincenty's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) in C#.
- if you need spatial on DB just go with Entity Framework 5/6.
- if you need further spatial operations in c# use something like NetTopologySuite. There's a NuGet for it and it's really simple to use.

Comment: I dont need db support, at least for now. All caculation are made in-memory. I used the algorithm from this answer and it seems to give correct result : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6545031/607162. That said, I had preffered a .net provided algorithm.

Comment: You can reference the SqlGeography/SqlGeometry types which are included on the Sql Server 2008/2012 types library, even without using a Database. They work perfectly fine on c#.

Comment: "_most of the classes on that library are abstract, hence up-to-you to be implement most-of-it._" - Hmm, not true at all. It is a bit of pain to create instances (and the docs suck). For anything but points, you need to do `SpatialBuilder.Create()` to get a builder then use the `GeographyPipeline` or `GeometryPipeline`.