# google API location distance calculation

Tags: .net

I am doing a project and i want to know how can I calculate the distance between 2 markers if it is between 20km? I want to know how to count the distance. 
Based on my code, I only can display the map and the marker.

Thank you!

```
        var TheFamilyPractice = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: 1.332419, lng: 103.867687},
            map: map
        });




        var contentTheFamilyPractice = '<div id="content">' +
            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">The Family Practice</h1>' +
            '<div id="bodyContent">' +
            '<p><b>Clinic Name: </b>The Family Practice </p> ' +
            '<p><b>Tel: </b>62816906 </p>' +
            '<p><b>Address: </b>148 Potong Pasir Ave 1, Singapore 350148</p>' +

            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
        var infowindow01 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentTheFamilyPractice
        });

        TheFamilyPractice.addListener('click', function () {
            infowindow01.open(map, TheFamilyPractice);
        });


        var Bankok = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: 1.332432, lng: 103.868321 },
            map: map
        });


        var contentBankok = '<div id="content">' +
            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Ban Kok Clinic & Surgery</h1>' +
            '<div id="bodyContent">' +
            '<p><b>Clinic Name: </b>Ban Kok Clinic & Surgery </p> ' +
            '<p><b>Tel: </b>62869955 </p>' +
            '<p><b>Address: </b>146 Potong Pasir Ave 1, Singapore 350146</p>' +

            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
        var infowindow02 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentBankok
        });

        Bankok.addListener('click', function () {
            infowindow02.open(map, Bankok);
        });
```

Comment: You have two coordinates, `{ lat: 1.332419, lng: 103.867687}` and `{ lat: 1.332432, lng: 103.868321 }`, and you want to calculate the actual distance (which is about 20km) between them? Right?

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate the actual distance between. Do you have any solution to help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the shortest distance, what is called the [Great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544286/calculate-distance-of-two-geo-points-in-km-c-sharp).

If you want the travel distance (as displayed on traffic map), check [Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro).

Comment: I am unsure of how can I use the code in the Google Maps Distance Matrix. I do not know which code to take to calculate the distance?

Comment: Construct a url using your coordinates and app key, and request the google service (sending a http GET request to the url), then you get the result from the response. It is explained well in that page.

Comment: Is it like the google map if I click on one of the markers and another marker it will display the distance between the 2 marker's distance on the map?

Comment: That seems to be the direct distance (Great circle distance). Which distance do you want? Direct distance or travel distance?

Comment: Direct Distance, hopefully can be like the google map measure the distance. But I think in the google map API do not have this kind of code.

Comment: Have you tried the method in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6545031/815938)?

Comment: yes I have tried the method when I put the code there is an error Console.WriteLine(DistanceAlgorithm.DistanceBetweenPlaces(36.578581, -118.291994, 36.23998, -116.83171));