# Google Maps API duration for specific route

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm writing an iOS application and need to get the duration time for a specific route (latitude, longitude points), how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Thanks to Jiri for his help!

Answer (score 2):

There are [various methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3) to calculate the distance between two points given by lat/lng. The simplest is to use the functions provided by the [spherical namespace](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#spherical) of Google Maps API v3:

```
computeDistanceBetween(from:LatLng, to:LatLng)
```

There is even a method to compute the length of a path:

```
computeLength(path:Array.<LatLng>|MVCArray.<LatLng>)
```

To use these methods you would need to initialize Maps as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jslibraries=geometry&sensor=false"> 
</script>
```

And if you know the distance and the velocity, you can compute the time.

Comment: Looks good, but is there a way to know the kind of street it is (highway, slow path ...) so I can compute a better approximation? How does google do to compute a route duration? Does it take in account the traffic? I would like to be as precise as possible... thanks

Comment: Forgot to ask even if the answer seems obvious: Does the distance computed takes in account the street curves?

Comment: The mentioned functions compute the distance between lat/lng points as you asked in your question. They obviously do not account for curves, etc. Also I am not aware how Google computes the traveling time on streets.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding... I'm looking for duration of a specific route (for a car), I thought there would be a function to get the duration by sending the route to a webservice for example.

Comment: I spent some time to answer your question as you asked it. There was nothing there about a route of a car or similar. I am sorry that I did not answer your indented question. It would be helpful when you make your question more precise.