# Outputting Distance Matrix results in a div

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421442/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-cities-using-google-maps-api-v3) to calculate the distance between places.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0r8pzz9w/3/) and the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
origin = new google.maps.LatLng(40.689844,-74.044874),
destination = "Washington, DC",
service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

service.getDistanceMatrix(
{
    origins: [origin],
    destinations: [destination],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
}, 
callback
);

function callback(response, status) {
    orig = document.getElementById("orig"),
    dest = document.getElementById("dest"),
    dist = document.getElementById("dist");

if(status=="OK") {
    orig.value = response.destinationAddresses[0];
    dest.value = response.originAddresses[0];
    dist.value = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
} else {
    alert("Error: " + status);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
Basic example for using the Distance Matrix.<br><br>
Origin: <input id="orig" type="text" style="width:35em"><br>
Destination: <input id="dest" type="text" style="width:35em"><br>
Distance from Statue of Liberty to Washington DC, USA (by car): <input id="dist" type="text" style="width:35em"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine, but I'd like to change input tags with div tags. However, if I change "input id" do "div id", it [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/0r8pzz9w/2/):

```
Origin: <div id="orig" type="text" style="width:35em"></div>
Destination: <div id="dest" type="text" style="width:35em"></div>
Distance from Statue of Liberty to Washington DC, USA (by car): <div id="dist" type="text" style="width:35em"></div>
```

Shouldn't it be irrelevant if it's a div, input, span or whatever, as long as it has that id? What should be changed to output the results in a div? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<div>` doesn't have a `value` property, only [input fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). You can set its [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) properties.

```
orig.innerHTML = response.destinationAddresses[0];
```