# Django- How to get my current location in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to get my current location in django so that I can compare the distance with my location and other city.

```
 lat1, lon1 = origin     #current location 
 lat2, lon2 = destination  #location of other city
```

Further I want to compare between these two for a distance. I have destination lat and long but looking for current lat and long

Comment: What do you expect to be the source of the location information?

Comment: I'm not sure but looking for some method that can automatically select my location.

Comment: On SO it is expected that you have done some research on the topic already.

Comment: I think you can use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7423314/2696165 its not django based, and probably it is best to use google maps api for that. You can also look into GeoDjango for distance calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want to use, but it looks like GeoLocation in Django will help you. Go through this documentation once. [GeoIP2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geoip2/).