# Google Maps - How to get the distance between two point in metre?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have these coordinate :

```
(45.463688, 9.18814) 
(46.0438317, 9.75936230000002)
```

and I need (trought Google API V3, I think) to get the distance between those 2 points in metre. How can I do it?

Comment: you can use distance matrix api if you are using it for distance and travel time.

Comment: Full answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3/50885562#50885562

Answer (score 125, accepted):

If you're looking to use the v3 google maps API, here is a function to use:
Note: you must add `&libraries=geometry` to your script source

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>

<script>
var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.463688, 9.18814);
var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.0438317, 9.75936230000002);

alert(calcDistance(p1, p2));

//calculates distance between two points in km's
function calcDistance(p1, p2) {
  return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
}

</script>
```

Comment: I added usage example, you need to pass 2 coords. It worked for me, returned 78.35

Comment: please don't forget to mark question as answered to help people in the future to find the right answer.

Comment: Does this return the value in miles or km?

Comment: As the comment says: //calculates distance between two points in km's

Comment: `console.log(calcDistance("45.463688, 9.18814", "46.0438317, 9.75936230000002"));` it returns NaN because we providing strings to `calDistance`. Try to make it `console.log(calcDistance(45.463688, 9.18814, 46.0438317, 9.75936230000002));`

Comment: What if you are passing the values using arrays? origLat[j], origLng[j]? IE returns NaN - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145901/ie-google-computedistancebetween-returns-nan

Comment: you can also use distance matrix api if you are using it for distance and travel time.

Comment: it does conflict with <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.27&key=AIzaSyDw79u95SUud5T_wtjb0zOG5E9QETaVQsU&signed_in=true&callback=Map"></script> ,

Comment: @Saurabh you just need to add &libraries=geometry to your own script reference, don't double up.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could do without any specific API, and calculate distance with plain Javascript:

[This](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) site has good info about geographical calculations and Javascript sample for distance calculation.

Ok, quick glance at Google API page and it seems, you could do it by:

1. Call DirectionsService().route() to get [DirectionsResult](http://code.google.com/intl/lv/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsResult) with routes
2. For one or each route go through its legs property and calculate sum of distances

Comment: Thank you for the first link. Calculation of close distances can be optimized much using aproximate formulas

Answer (score 1):

http://www.csgnetwork.com/gpsdistcalc.html

Has nothing to do with coding btw

EDIT
if you're looking for some code

[Calculate distance between two points in google maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)

Answer (score 1):

This is primarily done with math outside of the google api, so you shouldn't need to use the API for anything other than finding the correct coordinates.

Knowing that, here's a link to a previously answered question relating to Javascript.

[Calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates/365853#365853)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1;
 coord1.latitude = 45.463688;
 coord1.longitude = 9.18814;
 CLLocation *loc1  = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord1.latitude longitude:coord1.longitude] autorelease];

 CLLocationCoordinate2D coord2;
 coord2.latitude = 46.0438317;
 coord2.longitude = 9.75936230000002;
 CLLocation *loc2  = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:46.0438317 longitude:9.75936230000002] autorelease];

 CLLocationDistance d1 = [loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc2];
```

Comment: How to get route distance between 2 points, this just gives the direct distance(in physics literature: displacement), How to get path distance

Comment: that's objective C :) the question is about the Javascript API for google maps

Comment: Please provide explanation instead of "Try this".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const const toRadians = (val) => {
    return val * Math.PI / 180;
}
const toDegrees = (val) => {
    return val * 180 / Math.PI;
}
// Calculate a point winthin a circle
// circle ={center:LatLong, radius: number} // in metres
const pointInsideCircle = (point, circle) => {
    let center = circle.center;
    let distance = distanceBetween(point, center);

    //alert(distance);
    return distance < circle.radius;
};

const distanceBetween = (point1, point2) => {
   //debugger;
   var R = 6371e3; // metres
   var φ1 = toRadians(point1.latitude);
   var φ2 = toRadians(point2.latitude);
   var Δφ = toRadians(point2.latitude - point1.latitude);
   var Δλ = toRadians(point2.longitude - point1.longitude);

   var a = Math.sin(Δφ / 2) * Math.sin(Δφ / 2) +
           Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
           Math.sin(Δλ / 2) * Math.sin(Δλ / 2);
   var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

   return R * c;
}
```

References: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Please improve your answer. Why it is better, how it works, etc. "Try this" is not enough. Stackoverflow is not about trying things blindly but reading and understanding how things work. Still thank you for contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to distance as in length of the entire path or you want to know only the displacement (straight line distance)? I see no one is pointing the difference between distance and displacement here. For distance calculate each route point given by JSON/XML data, as for displacement there is a built-in solution using `Spherical` class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to distance as in length of the entire path or you want to know only the displacement (straight line distance)? I see no one is pointing the difference between distance and displacement here. For distance calculate each route point given by JSON/XML data, as for displacement there is a built-in solution using `Spherical` class. The idea is if your are referring to distance then you just use the `computeDistanceBetween` on each path point and concatenate it.

```
//calculates distance between two points in km's
function calcDistance(p1, p2) {
  return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
}
```