# Determine if location is within a certain region in Google Map

Tags: .net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

[image: Google Map]

In the Google Map shown above, there are 2 markers pointed by green arrows. They are the centers of 2 different regions indicated by blue circles in dotted lines. The marker pointed by an orange arrow lies within one of the aforementioned areas.

This brings up a problem.

Suppose there is a long list of locations of region center in the database, and all regions have the same fixed radius. **How can I implement the computation such that the system can tell me whether an arbitrary location on Google Map lies within at least one of the regions?** Iterating through the list of regions with a `for`-loop or `while`-loop in the source code is not an option, as performance is the first priority in my application.

**Are there any existing Google Map APIs or libraries which provide such functionalities?**

I am going to use Ionic for client and .NET C# for server, if it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Google Maps Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance).

If the area is a circle you can calculate the distance from the center, see for example on SO:
[How to detect if a point is in a Circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598426/how-to-detect-if-a-point-is-in-a-circle)

If the area is a Polygon see this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation