# Can I get the value of 1cm in a Map in Openlayers3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have to get the value of 1cm in a map with openlayers3 exist a way? For example if 1cm=5000km . How can I do it??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997627/google-maps-how-to-get-the-distance-between-two-point-in-metre   check out here to calculate distance between two points

Comment: That is not for me. I need to calculate the corresponding value of 1cm in a map of openlayers3

Comment: whats about if zoom in zoom out your map your 1cm ?

Comment: When I click on the map i wont to find the corresponding value of 1cm in the map. if I click before zooming I will find a bigger value on the contrary if I click after zooming i will find a smaller value

Comment: I understand but if zoom in zoom out your 1cm can become more or less   you can check here if found helpfull http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/measure.html

Comment: Or this one   http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29847/how-to-calculate-the-scale-of-current-zoom-level-with-parameters-like-extent-re