# How to find distance between any two markers on Google MAP javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, distance

I have  a javascript which fetches many Latlong from database and put it on Google Map. Now I want to find distance between any two markers. I have serched but was unable to find relevant information..

My Script is as below..

```js
var map,infoWindow;



function getData() {
    
     var lat1 = map.getCenter().lat();  
     var lng1= map.getCenter().lng();
     var zoom1 = map.getZoom();
      
      
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lng1),
        zoom: zoom1,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      
      
     infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
   
     downloadUrl("http://x.x.x.x/rfplan/getsitedata_1.php?ssa="+$("#ssa option:selected").text() +
            "&type="+$("#type option:selected").val() +
            "&make="+$("#make option:selected").val() +
            "&comm="+$("#comm option:selected").val() +
            "&sev="+$("#sev option:selected").val() +
            "&include="+$("#include option:selected").val() +
            "&can="+$("#cand option:selected").val() +
            "&ip_vand="+$("#vand option:selected").val(), function(data){
                
                
                var xml = data.responseXML;
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                  var address = markers[i].getAttribute("info");
                  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
                      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
                  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
                  var icon = customIcons[markers[i].getAttribute("color")] || {};
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: point,
                    icon: icon.icon
                  });
                  bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
                }
            
                           
        });    
        
        
        
    
}





function proc(){
    
    
}




    function load() {
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(22, 71),
        zoom: 7
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
      });
       infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    }
    
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };
            request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997627/google-maps-how-to-get-the-distance-between-two-point-in-metre  check once.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>

    <script>
    //calculates distance between two points in km's
    function calcDistance(p1, p2) {
      return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
    }

   var cordinateArr;
   //add this event in gmap script 

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (event) {
      cordinateArr.push(this.position);
      if(cordinateArr.length==2)
      {

        alert(calcDistance(cordinateArr[0], cordinateArr[1]));
        cordinateArr = [];
      }
     }); //end addListener
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but I have around 2000 markers. My problem is i don't know how to select two marker  from them..

Comment: So It seem you need to calculate distance for all markers right?? or for any two specific marker??

Comment: all 2000 markers are displayed on map and user want to select any two markers to find out distance between them...

Comment: Check my edited code when user click on specific marker it's coordinate will add in array and when user click on second coordinate it will calculate distance and reset array

Comment: Let me know if you have any confusion.

Comment: It worked like a charm... Only one thing i had to initialize array cordinateArr ....Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Geometry Lilbrary
Google Map Documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry