# In android, how to calculate the time which takes for a location change from one location to another

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am developing an app to calculate the user's speed with an android device.

this the code that I have developed

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Assign the new location
        mLastLocation = location;
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        List<Location> locationsList = new ArrayList<Location>();
        locationsList.add(location);
        avgSpeed = 0;
        speed = 0;
        totalSpeed=0;
        location.getTime();
     for(int i = 0; i < locationsList.size() ; i++) {

                 speed = calculateDistance(locationsList.get(i), locationsList.get(i+1))*1000/location.getTime()*3600;
                 totalSpeed+=speed;
                }
           avgSpeed = totalSpeed/locationsList.size();
}

        private long calculateDistance(Location location, Location location2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                double lat1= location.getLatitude();
                double lng1 = location.getLongitude();

                double lat2= location2.getLatitude();
                double lng2 = location2.getLongitude();

                double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
                double dLon = Math.toRadians(lng2 - lng1);
                double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                        + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                        * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
                        * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
                double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
                long distanceInMeters = Math.round(6371000 * c);
                return distanceInMeters;
            }
```

But I think that i cannot use the **getTime()** method to get  the time. **Is there any good solutions to calculate the time**

Answer (score 0):

```
Location location1 = new Location("");
location1.setLatitude(lat);
location1.setLongitude(long);

Location location2 = new Location("");
location2.setLatitude(lat);
location2.setLongitude(long);

float distanceInMeters = location1.distanceTo(location2);



//For example spead is 10 meters per minute.

int speedIs10MetersPerMinute = 10;
float estimatedDriveTimeInMinutes = distanceInMeters / speedIs10MetersPerMinute;
```

Answer from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8410867/1796309

Comment: I think this is for getting the distance . But, I want to to know the time taken for the location change. is there any methods to get the time???

Comment: First of all, you need to know a distance. If you know distance and speed, you can calculate the time. It is school physics. T = S / V, where S - distance, V - speed

Answer (score 0):

you could try to initialize a single variable in your `onCreate()` method, where to save the time at the beginning and then in the `onLocationChanged()` method you could get the time again and compare both times for example like this:

```
String string1 = "05:00:00 PM";
Date time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa").parse(string1);
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar1.setTime(time1);

String string2 = "09:00:00 AM";
Date time2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa").parse(string2);
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar2.setTime(time2);
calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

Date x = calendar1.getTime();
Date xy = calendar2.getTime();
long diff = x.getTime() - xy.getTime();
diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
float diffHours = diffMinutes / 60;
System.out.println("diff hours" + diffHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get **startTime** when getting **startLatitude** and **startLongitude**.
2. Get **endTime** when getting **endlatitude** and **endLongitude**.
3. Find the difference between them.
4. Done!