# Distance in Google maps

Tags: google-maps, apex-code

I am trying to add Google maps in Salesforce - Apex code; did so successfully. I also have 2 markers on the map. But now I want to find the distance between these 2 markers. Can anybody please help me to find the distance between the 2 markers in Google maps.

Please explain me how.

Thanks

Anuraj

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3/5349416#5349416

Answer (score 3):

There's a quick way using the geometry library. First, load it when adding the API (since it's optional)

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false">
</script>
```

Then call the measuring function:

```
meters = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
           markerA.getPosition(), markerB.getPosition());
```

(or enter LatLngs instead). The result is in meters.

Comment: thanks for you help. Can you please help me how to display it on an HTML page?

Comment: You can edit your question with Your HTML and then I'll see where this calculation should go.

Comment: can you tell me how can i display it any where. Just want to know what is the result coming i am not able to see the result. I asked you this because i want to make simple for you.

Comment: The result is in the variable meters in the example above. I wrote a demo so you can see the result distance between 2 markers. http://jsfiddle.net/nbCAy/1/