# Google maps api: get length of polyline in Serverside

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have polyline data in mysql. I want to measure its length in php. I have looked [distance matrix api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/). But it requests origin_addresses and destination_addresses , i haven't got those values.

I found [decodePolylineToArray](https://github.com/modolabs/Harvard-Mobile-Web/blob/master/mobi-lib/decodePolylineToArray.php) gist but when i decode my polyline, there are a lot of values. How can i measure length of polyline? I am using php but if you have a method in another language, i can port it to php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Haversine's formula for every Path in the polyline:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

For different programming languages search for :
https://www.google.ch/search?q=php+haversine+formula&aq=0&oq=php+Haversine&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3j62l2.8586&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

This is  a good sample for manual calculation in JS [Calculate distance between two points in google maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3), but there is a simpler way:

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(path.getAt(i), path.getAt(i+1));
```

Check out this sample:
http://www-users.mat.umk.pl/~kaskader/polyline_simple.html
that uses it.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i calculate distance with Haversine's formula, is it equal to Google maps native calculation? Yes, i know javascript have a lot of shortcut but i don't find easier solutions in web services api.

Comment: es. Using Haversine formula will give you the same results. What programming language do you need ?
You basically would need to rewrite this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1502821/1062708

Comment: It has worked. I used decodePolylineToArray gist and this gist http://pastebin.com/P711segA . Thank you so much.