# google maps get position

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google maps api, and I got a problem when I'm trying to get markers position.

I got two text fields as an address input, and i show the results with markers.

When I want to get the markers `position(by getPosition() function)`, for using new `google.maps.LatLngBounds()`, the markers position is correct on the map, but the `getPosition()` function, gives me a wrong answer, only on the second time I search for the address the `getPosition`, is updated for the first address search.

It's like it has a dealy and when I'm using `getPosition()`, the position is not updated yet.

Anyone have any idea why?

Thanx

This is part of my code.
If I'll use JSON request for getting the address location, will it work better?

```
function GetAddress(add , map , pointtype) {

    var country = 'france';        

    var address =  add + ', ' + country; 

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      if(pointtype == 0){
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {                

          origmarker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location) ;  
          origmarker.setTitle(add);


        } 
       });
      }
      else{
          geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {              

            desmarker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location) ;  
            desmarker.setTitle(add);


        } 
       });
      }
}

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds() ;

bounds.extend(origmarker.getPosition());
bounds.extend(desmarker.getPosition());

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: You have not really provided enough information. You should provide some code detailing what you are doing (see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between two points in google maps V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are using the geocoder to place the markers on the map.  The geocoder is asynchronous, you can't use the results until the callback routine runs.  Sounds like you are trying to use the position of the marker before the callback runs (so you get the value from the last call).

Comment: Thank you.you are right i'm using geocoder. is there a way to change it from asynchronous, or use a way for knowing when the callback returns?

Comment: No, you can't make it synchronous (that defeats the point).  You know the data is available when the callback runs.  Please update your question with the code you are using if you want more detailed answers.