# Google Maps API doesn't count distance between 2 cities

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I am trying to count the distance between two cities, here's the code:

```
function get_city_point(city) {
    var geocoder, point, result;
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    geocoder.geocode({address: city}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        result = results[0].geometry.location;
        point = result.lat() + "," + result.lng();
                console.log(point); // here's the coord.
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
    return point;
}

function count_the_distance(city1, city2) {
    var distance;
    var myp1 = new google.maps.LatLng(city1.split(',')[0], city1.split(',')[1]);
    var myp2 = new google.maps.LatLng(city2.split(',')[0], city2.split(',')[1]);

  return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(myp1, myp2)/1600).toFixed(2);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calculate_it').click(function(){
        var city1 = get_city_point(document.getElementById("from").value);
        console.log(city1);
        var city2 = get_city_point(document.getElementById("to").value);
        console.log(city2);
        var distance = count_the_distance(city1, city2);
        console.log(distance);
    });
...
```

When I take a look to the console, there's this output:

```
undefined app.js?body=1:153
undefined app.js?body=1:155
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined app.js?body=1:119
43.653226,-79.38318429999998 main.js?body=1:109
40.0583238,-74.4056612
```

It looks like the first **undefined** is the output of `console.log(city1);`, the second one of `console.log(city2);`, the `Uncaught TypeError` is from the function `count_the_distance` - because as parameters are passed 2 `undefined`s and the last two coordinations are from the `get_city_point` function - the `console.log(point)`.

So does it means that counting coordinations takes too much time and instead of returning lat+long it returns `undefined`?
Because the `console.log` in the function `get_city_point` shows that the coordination is counted.

Where's the problem in here?

Thank you guys.

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous, you can't return anything from it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to calculate polyline distance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796372/how-to-calculate-polyline-distance/15796891#15796891)