# Calculate distance in meters between two points

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm making a delivery site and I need to calculate the distance between two points and set a minimum price and multiply every 100 meters. How can this be done?

Comment: What programming language are you doing this in? HTML, Java, PHP, Objective-C, etc.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the *driving* distance (and you are displaying a Google Map), you can use the [directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) or the [directions matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)