# How to find other locations by given distance and coordinate in Google Maps

Tags: c#, linq, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have many locations in Google Maps. And in database(SQL Server) I stored their coordinates. Model is like this:

```
public class Marker
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Lat { get; set; }
   public string Long { get; set; }
}
```

`1 coordinate(latitude and longitude)` and `1 radius (i.e 100 meter)` will given to me, I should to find locations in this area inside radius from locations list.

How can I calculate distance by radius on coordinates?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after. Are you wanting to see if your marker is within a given distance of another location?

Comment: Yes, I need to calculate the distances between given coordinate and others, then if distance is less than given radius, to take that markers, to filter marker list.
To solve this I need to calculate the distance between locations with meter in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need use Haversine formula foreach point from given point and compare result with radius.

Comment: Thank, I research it now

Comment: Okay, now I am tring this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5040608/1534785  
then I will compare results.

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL query uses [**Spherical Law of Cosines**](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to calculate the distance between a coordinate and coordinates in a table.

> d = acos( sin(φ1).sin(φ2) + cos(φ1).cos(φ2).cos(Δλ) ).R

The query uses [**SQL Math functions**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177516.aspx)

```
"SELECT Id,Lat,Long,(6367 * acos( cos( radians(center_lat) )
  * cos( radians( Lat ) ) * cos( radians( Long ) - radians(center_lng) )
  + sin( radians(center_lat) ) * sin( radians( Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM table 
  HAVING distance < radius ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 20"
```

Using prepared statement for MS SQL & C#.

**Try**

```
private static void SqlCommandPrepareEx(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, connection);

        // Create and prepare an SQL statement.
        command.CommandText =
        "SELECT  Id, Lat, Long, (6367 * acos( cos( radians(@center_lat) ) * cos( radians( Lat ) ) * cos( radians( Long ) - radians(@center_lng) ) + sin( radians(@center_lat) ) * sin( radians( Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM table HAVING distance < @radius ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 20");
        SqlParameter center_lat = new SqlParameter("@center_lat", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        center_lat.Precision = 10;
        center_lat.Scale = 6;
        center_lat.Value = YOURVALUEHERE;//latitude of centre
        command.Parameters.Add(center_lat);
        SqlParameter center_lng = new SqlParameter("@center_lng", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        center_lng.Precision = 10;
        center_lng.Scale = 6;
        center_lng.Value = YOURVALUEHERE;//longitude of centre
        command.Parameters.Add(center_lng);
        SqlParameter radius = new SqlParameter("@radius", SqlDbType.Int,3);
        radius.Value = YOURVALUEHERE;
        command.Parameters.Add(radius);//Radius in km
        // Call Prepare after setting the Commandtext and Parameters.
        command.Prepare();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
}
```

As I don't have MS SQL & C#  I can't test

PS use 3956 for miles 6367 for kms