# Reorder <select> list of locations, based on distance to current GPS position

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, gps, html-lists

I have a website with a form containing a list of locations. I want the default selection to be the location closest to the current location of the user.

I know how to get the current GPS location using Javascript, but the problem is that getting the location take some time, and I want the form to displayed immediately, and just reorder/select the closest item when (or if) the location is retrived.

I've never used Jquery before - can someone give me some starting help?

The locations are stored in a MySQL DB and i use PHP to retrieve the data.

Comment: From a UX point, having the order of options change after the page has loaded would be extremely confusing, especially if the user is not expecting it to happen.

Comment: ^^ This, and (nearly) all lists should be in alphabetical order anyway.  Consistency is low enough on the internet without making it worse.  Nice idea, but I think your users would prefer alphabetical lists.

Comment: As @Archer says, alphabetical makes more sense. You could add the distance to the text value of the `option`, something like `London (35 miles), Paris (120 miles)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve this you should follow this steps:

- Store all locations contained in the select into the database along
  with their coords.
- Store user location coords into the session
- Select all locations from the database into an array and reorder it
  using the function below (user coords from the session and each location coords from the database)
- Display the new select from the array result

Originaly posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)

```
var rad = function(x) {
  return x * Math.PI / 180;
};

var getDistance = function(p1, p2) {
  var R = 6378137; // Earth’s mean radius in meter
  var dLat = rad(p2.lat() - p1.lat());
  var dLong = rad(p2.lng() - p1.lng());
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(rad(p1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(p2.lat())) *
    Math.sin(dLong / 2) * Math.sin(dLong / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c;
  return d; // returns the distance in meter
};
```