# Checking if 2 addresses are in the same location/region

Tags: javascript, php, api, geolocation

I'm trying to tackle this problem about checking whether 2 users are in the same location (could be as big as a region or as small as a suburb) using their addresses. I was just wondering if this is possible?

And if in case I don't have their addresses, can I use GPS to track those two? Is there any API that I could use from Google Maps regarding this?

Cheers.

PS: my app heavily uses PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: What do you mean by address? IP Address or mailing address. I don't see any reason you need to compare mailing address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use google geocoding
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Geocoding
then try to calculate distance between point like it was suggested here:
[Calculate distance between two points in google maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)