# Adding the measure distance feature to google maps api

Tags: api, maps, distance, measure

Just curious if anyone knows how to implement the "measure distance" feature found in google maps to the google maps api.

I would like to be able to right-click and have the same functionality that google maps has... any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: I presume you want a function that takes a pair of lat/longs and computes the distance?

Comment: Yes, and I've seen other people make something, but what I want is the default builtin distance measure that google maps now has... I'm kind of surprised they haven't integrated it into the api.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to implement this with the "Distance Matrix API" and this node package saved my life:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/measuretool-googlemaps-v3

You just have to install it with:

```
npm i measuretool-googlemaps-v3
```

Include the **MeasureTool.min.js** file in your code.

And create a new measure tool object for the `google.maps.Map` instance:

```
measureTool = new MeasureTool(map, {
  showSegmentLength: true,
  tooltip: true,
  unit: MeasureTool.UnitTypeId.METRIC // metric, imperial, or nautical
});
```

Then you will be able to right-click and have the same functionality that google maps have.

[Live Demo](https://www.leafyjava.com/p/measurement-tool-for-google-maps-api-v3.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all of their APIs but this one can compute a distance matrix.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Otherwise you can see this answer:

[Calculate distance between two points in google maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at those and I've found other rulers, I'm specifically looking to see if there was a way to get the google maps 'measure distance' feature into the maps api. I've found other rulers, but want that one specifically. This is the one I'm referring to: http://mashable.com/2014/07/09/google-maps-measure-distances/

Comment: Hi, @MarkReimer finally did you find a way to achieve it?