# My map v3 distance calculation gives ambiguos and likely wrong result

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps-api-3

am working android project using web languages on android webview. I tried to calculate the distance between a user location and other places location, but it keeps giving me large values and the same time, the same value of distance for all the places search result. I tested other application result, but my own seems different. Every other thing works fine, except the value of the distance which is the same for all places irrespective of there distance, and always different from the value other similar apps from Google pay store give. My code is below for assistance.

```
    var map, places, infoWindow;
    var geocoder;
    var pos;

    function initialize() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false
      };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);

      // Try HTML5 geolocation
      if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
           pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          map.setCenter(pos);
           }, function() {
          handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
      }


      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: document.getElementById('info-content')
          });

      // Create the autocomplete object and associate it with the UI input control.
      // Restrict the search to the default country, and to place type "cities".
      places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
      document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
          });

     // Add a dom event listener to react when the user clicks the search button

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('button'), 'click',
          onPlaceChanged);

    }

    function distance () {
        places.textSearch(search, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

             var service5 = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
              service5.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
          origins: [pos],
          destinations: [results[i].geometry.location],
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
        }, callback);

        function callback(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {


         document.getElementById('iw-distance1').textContent  = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
         document.getElementById('iw-time').textContent  = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text; 
             }
           else {
           alert ("helo");
             } 
           } 
        }
      }
    } 
   } 
       function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
      if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
      } else {
        var content = 'Error: Doesn\'t support geolocation.';
      }

      var options = {
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
        content: content
      };

      map.setCenter(options.position);
    }

            <tr id="iw-website-row" class="iw_table_row">
              <td class="iw_attribute_name">distance:</td>
              <td id="iw-distance1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="iw-website-row" class="iw_table_row">
              <td class="iw_attribute_name">time:</td>
              <td id="iw-time"></td>
            </tr>


         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: in your `distance` function, you refer to `results[i]` - what's `i`, I don't see anywhere  you're setting that

Comment: yes your right ,I was rushing didn't post the complete code. I want to calculate distance using users location and the position of each marker. I tried to use "place.vucinity" to get addresses of places returned from my textsearch but, it keeps giving me the same value for all the search results. Please is there any better approach to calculating distance. My method returns value but the results are wrong.

Comment: All you need to know about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3