# Getting distance(in kms) from map center to start/end position of map - Google Maps Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I get distance(in kms) from mapCenter() to start/end position of map using **Google Maps Javascript**? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Straight line distance - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3

Comment: I am only having the mapCenter() lat, lng(**say** p1). How can I get the left start/right end lat, lng(**say** p2) in map?

Comment: That would be https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en - `getBounds()` (just above `getCenter()` - which I presume you know about)

Comment: I am new to Google Maps Javascript API. When I use getBounds() in console, I am getting as Ea(G and j parameters inside) and Ja(G and j parameters inside) object parameters. Which one should I take for p2 lat, lng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably looking for a [`getBounds` function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference):

> Returns the lat/lng bounds of the current viewport. If more than one
>   copy of the world is visible, the bounds range in longitude from -180
>   to 180 degrees inclusive. If the map is not yet initialized (i.e. the
>   mapType is still null), or center and zoom have not been set then the
>   result is null or undefined.

Then you could utilize [Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) in particular `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween` function to calculate distance between two points (in meters by default).

**Example**

```js
function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(55.755327, 37.622166);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
       var bounds = map.getBounds();
       var start = bounds.getNorthEast();
       var end = bounds.getSouthWest();
       var distStart = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (center, start) / 1000.0;
       var distEnd = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (center, end) / 1000.0;
      

       document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Distiance from center to start:' + distStart; 
       document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Distiance from center to end:' + distEnd + '<br/>'; 

    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 350px;"></div>
<div id='output'/>
```

Comment: I checked with your code and its working fine. But I have used the '<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>'. If I do replace the libraries using geometry, the places API not working. How to solve this?

Comment: You just need to load both `places` and `geometry` libraries: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=geometry,places
For more details follow  [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries) documentation

Comment: I loaded both using **libraries=geometry,places**. Now all good. Thanks a lot for your time