# Google Maps: Restrict the user to move the marker maximum of 800 meters from the position on load

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I have a scenario, in which i need to restrict the user to move the marker only for 800 mts, from the given position.
I am using React and Google Maps.

Kindly provide some inputs.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can try with [google API example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-bounds-restriction) of restricting area.

Comment: Hi @Rado, Thanks, But the API Example is based on bounds. I need to set based on meters.

Comment: You can approximately convert meters to a latitude and longitude, and set bounds accordingly. See Rado's link as well as [this](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: You can also check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558185/getting-distancein-kms-from-map-center-to-start-end-position-of-map-google-m) of calculating the distance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain further your use case? Assuming that you initially have a marker and you would like to only allow pinning your marker 800 meters away from the center you set, you can use a draggable marker with eventListener on dragend. Once the marker drag ends, you will then get the coordinates of the new position of the marker. You will use this coordinate and the coordinate of the center to calculate if the distance between them is greater than 800m using [computeDistanceBetween() of the Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance). You will use a conditional statement to check if the distance is within 800m, you will pin that marker to that coordinate and if it is greater than 800m, you will put an alert about it and pin the marker to the previous pinned position.

Here's a code snippet:

```
//markerA is the center
          let markerA = new window.google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: 41.0082, lng: 28.9784 },
            map: map,
            label:"A",
          });
//markerB is the draggable marker
          let markerB = new window.google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: 41.0072, lng: 28.9784 },
            map: map,
            label:"B",
            draggable:true,
          });
//previousB will be the variable that hold previous coordinate of markerB
          let previousB;
//eventlistener for markerB that listens to the dragend

          markerB.addListener("dragend", function (endOfDrag) {
            let newLat = endOfDrag.latLng;
//using computeDistanceBetween() to get the distance            
            let dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
              map.center,
              newLat
            );
//conditional statement            
            if (dist <= 800) {
              alert("Coordinate is inside  800 meters!");
//set the new position to previousB variable
              previousB = endOfDrag.latLng;
            } else {
              alert("Coordinate is more than 800 meters away!");
//pin the markerB back to previous position
              markerB.setPosition(previousB)
            }
          });
```

Here is a [sample reactjs code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/draggable-marker-tce1nc-jbmhe9?file=App.js) that implements this.

Comment: thanks for your input. I have just finished the job by creating a circle of 800 mtrs and restricting my marker inside the circle.