# Calculate distance between users location and all the markers on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Done some Google Mpas stuff by myself, but stopped on distance calculating.
I have a function for locating users current location marker:

```
function myLocationMarker(latLng) {
    var markerOptions = {
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        clickable: true
    }
    var myMarker = new MarkerWithLabel(markerOptions);
```

And this function places other markers. I get the data from database, and it places about 1000 markers.

```
var markers = []; //blank array from markers
function addMarker(lat, lng, info) { //info - needed for database
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //marker options
        position: pt,
        icon: icon,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker); //pushing every marker to markers array
```

But what I need is distance between them.
How I can calculate distance between `myLocationMarker` and every other marker on map from `addMarker` function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `directionsService` being aware that the distance between two markers on a map depends on the [travelling mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TravelModes) you choose (`"DRIVING"`, `"WALKING"`, `"BICYCLING"`, `"TRANSIT"`).

If you want to compute air distance you will need some geometry with the Haversine formula (check the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1502821/2314737)

Here's an example with `"DRIVING"`

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB, outputTxt) {
  var selectedMode = "DRIVING";
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

      outputTxt.innerHTML = Math.round(directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[directionsDisplay.getRouteIndex()].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) + "Km";
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Here's a demo
http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/fLogwsff/

EDIT: alternatively, you can use the `computeDistanceBetween` function from the [spherical geometry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) package

> **computeDistanceBetween**(from:*LatLng*, to:*LatLng*, radius?:number)
>   Return Value:  number Returns the distance, in meters, between two LatLngs.
>   You can optionally specify a custom radius. The radius defaults to the
>   radius of the Earth.

```
var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pointA, pointB);
// by default distance is in meters
distance = Math.round(distance/ 1000) + "Km";
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/qxrg4o3y/