# Googlemaps : Distance between two points on a route specified

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, routes, google-distancematrix-api

Good day to all.

I am currently developing an application on android studio, which calculates the distance traveled by the user from a start point to your current position, I read that the Google Maps API Distance Matrix allows me to calculate the distance between two known points (the first serious static and the second point would vary depending on the position of the user)

The question I have is: how to make the API google calculate the distance along the path I want, and not the most optimal route between two points, (the route to be taken by users will always be the same).

Please express your support is me

Greetings to everyone from Cucúta Colombia.

Comment: have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about something like this perhaps? [Distance Finder](http://www.mapdevelopers.com/distance_finder.php)

It's the perfect example for me, I hope it be util for anybody more. Bye.