# Google Places API closest supermarket

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, distance

I know I can find the closest supermarkets with this Google API like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.360229, 6.042169&radius=3000&type=supermarket&key=myKey
```

But now I get many results.

How do I only get the closest one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `rankby` option with `distance` parameter

```
var request = {
  location: gps,
  types: ['grocery'],
  rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE, 
  key: key 
};
```

reference : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

once you have multiple location use `haversine formula` to get the distance between two locations.

```
 function distance(p1, p2) {
      if (!p1 || !p2) 
       return 0;
      var R = 6371000; // Radius of the Earth in m
      var dLat = (p2.lat() - p1.lat()) * Math.PI / 180;
      var dLon = (p2.lng() - p1.lng()) * Math.PI / 180;
      var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
      Math.cos(p1.lat() * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(p2.lat() * Math.PI / 180) *
      Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
      var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
      var d = R * c;
      return d;
     }
```

reference : https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Thanks but then I still get multiple results. I only want 1 result!

Comment: then you can find shortest distance out of array of results. you have to find the distance between two points(locations). have a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json? 
     location=51.360229,6.042169&radius=3000&type=grocery&key=vaquarkhan&rankBy? 
        google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE
```